# UITabBarItem finishedImageSelected placed offsetting the tab bar

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5

I'm trying to customize UITabBarItem but I'm having problems with the image's position.

[image]

The image size is 81px x 49px, the same height as the UITabBar. This is how I set the image:

```
    // AppDelegate
    BlocosController *blocos = [[[BlocosController alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:moc] autorelease];
    UINavigationController *navBlocos = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:blocos] autorelease];
    tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:moc];
    tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: navData, navBlocos, navBairro, navAtualizar, nil];

// ...

// BlocosController.m

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.tabBarItem = [[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:TITLE image:nil tag:10] autorelease];
        [[self tabBarItem] setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_bar_blocos_selected"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_bar_blocos_unselected"]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

<del>I've search on google and found [this tutorial](http://appledmg.com/tuts/?p=52), the code uses the same API as I use and works as expected.</del> *The code in this article behaves just like mine, but since their background is the same color there's a illusion of it been correctly placed.*

Why is the finishedImageSelected and the unselected are placed unaligned with the tab tab? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the correct way to accomplish this and made a post: [felipecypriano.com/2012/02/27/…](http://felipecypriano.com/2012/02/27/how-to-customize-uitabbar-on-ios-5/).

Basically the problem is that finishedImage is the icon not the icon and the background, it's possible to use with the background by adjusting the imageInset property.